# Upload Files to Folders in BOX.com from Android sdk

Tags: android, box-api

I am getting stuck while upload files to my custom folder on box.com ,
I am using BOX Api in android, I had tried with below code

```
BoxFileUploadRequestObject upload = BoxFileUploadRequestObject.uploadFileRequestObject(folderId, "Sample File.txt", sampleFile);
                getClient().getFilesManager().uploadFile(upload);
```

Please guide me How can I upload files to my custom folder on Box ?

Comment: are u getting any errors or messages??

Comment: Did you upload files through File Chooser in android?  If yes please share the code.How can I upload to BOX.com from android device using android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your folder by following below step

1)You need to first get your folderID by using below code

```
                    BoxAndroidFolder folder = data.getParcelableExtra(FolderPickerActivity.EXTRA_BOX_ANDROID_FOLDER);
```

data*-  your OnActivityResulr intent type data

2)`folder.getid()`  hold it as string variable 
3)pass this id to

```
BoxFileUploadRequestObject upload = BoxFileUploadRequestObject.uploadFileRequestObject(folderId, "Sample File.txt", sampleFile);
            getClient().getFilesManager().uploadFile(upload);
```

Comment: Is this solution for your question?

Comment: @BABUK yes as per version

Comment: I want to choose a document using android file chooser ,then upload the choosed document to box's folder.My question is how do you upload a document using file chooser?

Comment: @BABUK I have worked on BOX a year ago so can not guide exactly but you can refer BOX documentation for latest updated version.